# How to get stored procedure out type value in mvc c# List<T> type public function

Tags: c#, sql-server, model-view-controller, sqlconnection, sqlcommand

I am trying to get total count of records in "@TotalRecordsCount" which will be returned after applying all my search parameters. but it is always giving me null value. i tried other matching options and try to fix it but my code it written different way to execute stored procedure based queries. Given below code is sending request to code written to access database

Code # 1

```
 public List<T> GetAllUsedCarsSidSearchFiltered<T>(string vehicleTypeIDs, string makeIDs, string modelIDs, int yearsStarting, int yearsEnding,
        int MileageStarting, int MileageEnding, string transmissionIDs, string noOfDoors, string fuleTypes, string bodyTypesIDs, string carsColors
        , string pcpfilterValue, string hpfilterValue, int totalRecordsCount, string storedProcedureName)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var connection = DbConnection.GetOpenConnectionKapMotorsContextMultiSelect())
            {
                return connection.Query<T>(storedProcedureName, new
                {
                    vehicleTypeIDs,
                    makeIDs,
                    modelIDs,
                    yearsStarting,
                    yearsEnding,
                    MileageStarting,
                    MileageEnding,
                    transmissionIDs,
                    noOfDoors,
                    fuleTypes,
                    bodyTypesIDs,
                    carsColors,
                    pcpfilterValue,
                    hpfilterValue,
                    totalRecordsCount
                }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            throw exception;
        }
    }
```

this given below code is sending request to database.

Code # 2

```
 public static SqlConnection GetOpenConnectionKapMotorsContextMultiSelect()
    {
        var connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ProviderConnectionString);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SideSearchBar_GetUsedCarsBySearchFilters", connection);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlParameter outputParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@TotalRecordsCount", SqlDbType.Int);
        outputParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        connection.Open();

        //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        int TotalRecordsCount = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@TotalRecordsCount"].Value);
        return connection;
    }
```

when I run this stored procedure from "execute procedure", it returns the required result and TotalRecordCount value. but not in c# code. Please guide me

Answer (score 0):

That's probably cause you are not executing the query at all, as seen in your posted code this line is commented `//cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: @ rahul : when i uncomment the exucutenonquery() it still fetch null value in TotalRecordsCount